# dart maps - as efficient as switch or if statements under the hood?

Tags: dictionary, dart

say I do this:

```
var choice = 2;
runThis(
  {
    1: getThis(),
    2: getThat(),
    3: getSomethingElse(),
  }[choice]
);
```

You can see I'm making a map to choose what to I want to pass to a function.

If the interpreter knows choice is 2 when it gests to the point of making the map it doesn't have to build 1: or 3: values does it?

Basically I'm wondering if above is less efficient than below:

```
var choice = 2;
var value;
if (choice == 1) {
  value = getThis();
} else if (choice == 2) {
  value = getThat();
} else if (choice == 3) {
  value = getSomethingElse();
} 
runThis(value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is of course it builds the entire map first, not smart enough not to. But you can move the execution out if the values are functions so that all that is built is the reference to the function, which I assume would be just as efficient as an If statement, maybe.

```
print({
  1: getThis,
  2: getThat,
}[2]!());

String getThis() {
  print('This');
  return 'this';
}

String getThat() {
  print('That');
  return 'that';
}
```

> That
> that

Comment: It still wouldn't be as efficient as an `if` statement for a number of reasons: It would build a `Map` object, perform a virtual function call for the `operator []` access, apply a `null`-check at runtime when using `!`, and perform another function call to invoke the callback.

Comment: If you can make the map `const`, which you can here, then you won't have to create a map every time you do the dispatch. Still, just use a `switch`. That's actually optimized for going directly to the correct case.